Docker Zabbix wmi
I hope I can find here some help or hints. I am new to docker and zabbix.
I am trying to make a dockerfile and a docker-compose for zabbix monitoring with the zbxwmi plugin.
Somehow I am very stuck to change the permission for the script to have the permission in the container to use it. If I check it on the container I get with exec the permission for
ubuntu:ubuntu but I think I have to change it like my zabbix user with the name zabbix and he needs root permisson to use the zbxwmi script, because my user is zabbix within my zabbix ngix frontend. I hope I can get here some help.
thank you in advance
I have changed the host chmod the Result
https://github.com/13hakta/zbxwmi

root@zabbixwmi:/home/zabbix/container-files/etc/zabbix# chmod 640 /home/zabbix/container-files/etc/zabbix/wmi.pw root@zabbixwmi:/home/zabbix/container-files/etc/zabbix# ls -l /home/zabbix/container-files/etc/zabbix/wmi.pw -rw-r----- 1 zabbix zabbix 96 Apr 9 06:11 /home/zabbix/container-files/etc/zabbix/wmi.pw
root@zabbixwmi:/home/zabbix/container-files/etc/zabbix#
User root@zabbixwmi:/home/zabbix/container-files/etc/zabbix# ls -l /home/zabbix/container-files/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/zbxwmi -rwxr--r-- 1 zabbix zabbix 6900 Nov 27 2020 /home/zabbix/container-files/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/zbxwmi root@zabbixwmi:/home/zabbix/container-files/etc/zabbix#

my folder and file structure:

zabbix

db_dumb.sh
db_restore.sh
docker-compose.yml
dockerfile
entrypoint.sh
zabbix_server.conf

container-files

     etc

        ssl

             apache
           
             grafana
             
             nginx            

        zabbix
            
          nginx.conf
          wmi.pw

     usr

         lib
           
           zabbix

                externalscripts
 
                    zbxwmi
 
           local

              share

                  zabbix

                      externalscripts

                          zbxwmi

 grafana
  
   (not the priority right now)

 sh
 
    build.sh
    create_user.sh

 ssl

dockerfile

# Use the official Ubuntu image as the base image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Set environment variables to prevent interactive prompts during package installation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Create a user named "zabbix" with root privileges
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash zabbix && \
    usermod -aG sudo zabbix && \
    echo 'zabbix:password' | chpasswd

# Update package lists and install necessary packages for your main application
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nginx \
    wget \
    postgresql-client \
    python3-six \
    python3-pycryptodome \
    python3-pyasn1 \
    python3-pip \
    openssl \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Generate German locale and update locale settings
RUN locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8 && update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

# Install Zabbix repository and Zabbix packages
RUN wget https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/zabbix/zabbix/6.4/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_6.4-1%2Bubuntu22.04_all.deb && \
    dpkg -i zabbix-release_6.4-1+ubuntu22.04_all.deb && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    zabbix-server-pgsql \
    zabbix-frontend-nginx \
    zabbix-nginx-conf \
    zabbix-agent \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Grafana
RUN wget -q -O - https://packages.grafana.com/gpg.key | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/grafana.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y grafana && \
    apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Impacket for WMI
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install impacket

# Copy Zabbix NGINX configuration file
COPY container-files/etc/zabbix/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

# Create directory for external scripts
RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/

# Copy external scripts
COPY container-files/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/zbxwmi /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/zbxwmi
COPY container-files/etc/zabbix/wmi.pw /etc/zabbix/wmi.pw

# Set permissions and ownership for scripts
RUN chmod +x /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/zbxwmi && \
    chmod 700 /etc/zabbix/wmi.pw && \
    chown zabbix:zabbix /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/zbxwmi && \
    chown -R zabbix:zabbix /etc/zabbix/wmi.pw

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 10050/tcp 10051/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp

# Copy entrypoint script
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# Set execute permission for the entrypoint script
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Set the entrypoint script as the entry point for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Set the zabbix user as the default user for subsequent commands
USER zabbix

docker-compose

version: '3.8'

services:
  zabbix-server:
    image: ${ZABBIX_SERVER_IMAGE:-zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql:ubuntu-6.4-latest}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "10051:10051"
    environment:
      DB_SERVER_HOST: postgres
      DB_SERVER_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - network-zabbix
    volumes:
      - ./container-files/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts:/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts
      - ./container-files/etc/zabbix/wmi.pw:/etc/zabbix/wmi.pw

  zabbix-frontend:
    image: ${ZABBIX_FRONTEND_IMAGE:-zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql:6.4-ubuntu-latest}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    environment:
      DB_SERVER_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      PHP_TZ: ${TZ}
      ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-server
      ZBX_SERVER_PORT: 10051
    depends_on:
      - zabbix-server
    networks:
      - network-zabbix

  zabbix-agent:
    image:  ${ZABBIX_AGENT_IMAGE:-zabbix/zabbix-agent:6.4-ubuntu-latest}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "10050:10050"
    environment:
      ZBX_ACTIVE_ALLOW: ""  # or null, depending on your preference
      TZ: ${TZ}
      ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-server
      ZBX_SERVER_PORT: 10051
      ZBX_HOSTNAME: zabbix-agent
      ZBX_HOSTNAMEITEM: system.hostname
    depends_on:
      - zabbix-server
    networks:
      - network-zabbix
    volumes:
      - ./container-files/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts:/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts
      - ./container-files/etc/zabbix/wmi.pw:/etc/zabbix/wmi.pw

  postgres:
    image: ${POSTGRES_IMAGE:-postgres:latest}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    networks:
      - network-zabbix

  grafana:
    image: ${GRAFANA_IMAGE:-grafana/grafana}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER: ${GRAFANA_USER:-admin}
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${GRAFANA_SECRET:-12345}
      GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS: alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app
      TZ: ${TZ}
    user: "472"
    volumes:
      - grafana:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - ./grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
    depends_on:
      - zabbix-frontend
    networks:
      - network-zabbix

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./ssl/nginx:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - ./ssl/apache:/etc/apache2/ssl
      - ./ssl/grafana:/etc/grafana/ssl
    networks:
      - network-zabbix

volumes:
    postgres: {}
    grafana: {}

networks:
  network-zabbix:
    driver: bridge

entrypoint.sh

#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Set permissions and ownership for external scripts
chown -R zabbix:zabbix /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts
chown zabbix:zabbix /etc/zabbix/wmi.pw

# Start PostgreSQL service
service postgresql start

# Start Nginx service
service nginx start

# Start Zabbix server
service zabbix-server start

# Start Zabbix agent
service zabbix-agent start

# Tail the Nginx error log to keep the container running
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

wmi.pw

USER root
RUN echo -e "zabbix\password\localhost" > /etc/zabbix/wmi.pw
USER non-root-user

build.sh

#!/bin/bash
docker build --pull --rm -f "DockerBuild\Dockerfile" -t docker:latest "DockerBuild"

create_user.sh

#!/bin/sh
if ! id -u zabbix > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    useradd -ms /bin/bash zabbix
fi

zabbix_server.conf (not in use)

### Option: ListenPort
#       Listen port for trapper.
#       No default.
#       Mandatory: no
#       Range: 1024-32767
# ListenPort=

### Option: ListenIP
#       List of comma delimited IP addresses that the trapper should listen on.
#       Default:
#       ListenIP=0.0.0.0

### Option: HousekeepingFrequency
#       How often Zabbix server should perform housekeeping procedure in
#       seconds.
#       No default, -1 - disable housekeeping.
#       Mandatory: no
#       Range: -1-86400
# HousekeepingFrequency=1

### Option: StartPollers
#       Number of pre-forked instances of pollers.
#       Default:
#       StartPollers=5

db_dumb.sh (perheaps it has to be zabbix not zabbixadmin)

#!/bin/sh
# RUN BEFORE UPGRADING POSTGRES IMAGE.
docker compose down
 
docker compose up -d db
docker compose exec postgres pg_dumpall -U zabbixadmin > pgdump.sql
docker compose down

db_restore.sh (perheaps it has to be zabbix not zabbixadmin)

#!/bin/sh
# RUN AFTER UPGRADING POSTGRES IMAGE.

docker compose up -d db
cat pgdump.sql | docker compos postgres zabbix_db_1 psql -U zabbixadmin -d zabbix
docker compose down

nginx.conf

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /usr/share/zabbix;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # Adjust version as needed
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

I am trying to use the plugin within zabbix but somehow I have no permisson to use it.
new item
Permission denied
Execute
